# Утечка памяти в nodejs socket.io при реконекте клиента

Tags: node.js, socket.io, утечка-памяти

Есть клиент, который соединяеться на сокет, общаеться с сервером nodejs и отсоединяеться. При каждом реконекте сервер начинает все больше есть памяти, за месяц сьедает 1.5 Gb оперативки (по условиям задачи нельзя чтоб демон падал, по этому перезапуск не вариант)

```
var _io = io.of('/signal')
_io.on('connection', function (client) {
    var geoData,
        clientIp,
        onDisconnect = function () {
            client.removeListener('get_last', onGetLast);
            client.removeListener('login', onLogin);
            client.removeListener('logout', onLogout);
            client.removeListener('is_logged', onIsLogged);
            client.removeListener('disconnect', onDisconnect);

            delete onGetLast;
            delete onLogin;
            delete onLogout;
            delete onIsLogged;
            delete onDisconnect;
            delete geoData;
            delete clientIp;
        },
        onGetLast = function () {
            config.DEBUG && console.log('on `get_last`');

            if ('guests' === client.room) {
                client.emit('receive_signals', DATA.lastSignalsTime.slice(-10));
            } else if ('logged' === client.room) {
                client.emit('receive_signals', DATA.lastSignals.slice(-10));
            }
        },
        onLogin = function (code) {
            config.DEBUG && console.log('on `login`', code);

            if (code === config.loginCode) {
                client.leave('guests');
                client.join('logged');
                client.room = 'logged';
                //output = signals;
            }
        },
        onLogout = function () {
            config.DEBUG && console.log('on `logout`');

            client.leave('logged');
            client.join('guests');
            client.room = 'guests';
        },
        onIsLogged = function () {
            config.DEBUG && console.log('on `is_logged`');

            var result;

            if ('logged' === client.room) {
                result = 1;
            } else {
                result = 0; // room 'guest'
            }

            client.emit('is_logged_res', result);
        };

    clientIp = 'production' === config.NODE_ENV ? _.getClientIp(client) : '128.101.101.101';
    geoData = DATA.mmdb.countries.getGeoDataSync(clientIp);

    client.room = 'guests';
    client.join('guests');

    client.on('disconnect', onDisconnect);
    client.on('get_last', onGetLast);

    //check if clients country is valid
    if (!geoData
        || !('object' === typeof geoData.country
        && null !== geoData.country
        && 'string' === typeof geoData.country.iso_code
        && -1 === DATA.invalidCountries.indexOf(geoData.country.iso_code))
    ) {
        return;
    }

    client.on('login', onLogin);
    client.on('logout', onLogout);
    client.on('is_logged', onIsLogged);
});
```

Comment: Съедает 1.5 Гб оперативки... и дальше что? Ест ещё? Падает?

Comment: продолжает нормально работать, не падает, но продолжает есть, при каждом реконекте.
Нормального профайлера не нашел, который укажет где именно остаються данные, только через node-inspector вижу что ест при реконекте и все.

Comment: Это странно, насколько я знаю, у V8 лимит потребления heap по умолчанию 1.4 Гб.

Comment: даже 1.5 Гб это много как для сервера который после нагрузки обслуживает 1-го юзера, а занимает памяти как будто пару тысяч юзеров.
Возможно я как-то сам провоцирую эту утечку в своем коде, что-то не очищаю?

Comment: Не факт, что это вообще утечка, а не особенность работы сборщика мусора. Пошарьтесь на предмет того, как уменьшить лимит.

Comment: если вам нужно чтобы демон не падал, то вы выбрали не тот стек технологий. не знаю ни одного более-менее крупного nodejs приложения которое было бы стабильно.

Comment: я знаю http://iatacodes.org/ им пользуеться компания Boeing, написан он на ноде

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо, [Кнопкатык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/181100/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA/)

Решил проблемму добавлением параметра

```
--max_old_space_size
```

и при событии **disconnect**, вручную удаляю события навешаные на клиента методом

```
socket.removeListener('event_name', onEvenCallback);
```